# Building workspace error while creating groovy class in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I am new to Groovy or any programming language and new to Eclipse as well.
I am following a tutorial on youtube which shows us how to install Eclipse Oxygen and then add plugin of Groovy.
I followed everything and created Groovy project but while creating the class it gives me below error(Screenshot attached).
Could you please guide on how can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Eclipse Details :
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)

Java Version : 1.8.0_231

Groovy version : 3.0.3 JVM 1.8.0_231

My OS : Windows 10
[Error Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtLhG.png)

Comment: Please post your code, or is this at creation of a new class ? What vwersion of Java are you running ? What version of groovy-eclipse ? Are you using Eclipse-JEE ?

Comment: Eclipse Details :
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)

Java Version : 1.8.0_231

Groovy version : 3.0.3 JVM 1.8.0_231

My OS : Windows 10

Comment: Create a Groovy script (right-click Project/src -> new File) in the project/src. Put `println 'test'` in it and run it with right-click -> Run As -> Groovy Script. Let's see what happens.

Comment: Thanks @ou_ryperd , but when I right click on src file and try to create a class , that's when it gives me the error. I have attached error screenshot to the main question.So I don't get to reach the point where I can write the code.

Comment: Yes. Don't create a class. Groovy is not Java, you don't need a class, you can have a script. I want to see if Groovy works at all, hence my instrauctions, but if you're not going to follow my troubleshooting instructions then I'm wasting my time.

Comment: Thanks @ou_ryperd , As per your advice I installed the latest Eclipse and repeated the steps of installing Groovy plugin.Now its working.But I dont know how to mark your answer as correct, this is my first question on stackoverflow.

Comment: What update site did you use to install the Groovy Development Tools?  The GDT patches JDT (Java Development Tools) and must be version matched with the Eclipse that you are using (Oxygen in your case).  "isReconcile" is an old method that has been replaced in newer GDT versions, which leads me to believe you have unmatched tooling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest you try a newer version of Eclipse, it shouldn't impact a tutorial's steps.